# how to insert html into a div Class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert HTML codes into a div **Class**, But It doesn't seem to work. I have included my code below. Need some help in inserting an HTML code in Javascript.

Using `.getElementById` works:

```js
document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = '<div id=test11>Test 1!</div>';
```

```html
<span id="test1"></span>
```

But using `getElementsByClassName` nothing happened:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('test2').innerHTML = '<div id=test22>Test 2!</div>';
```

```html
<span class="test2"></span>
```

Comment: *"But using getElementsByClassName nothing happened"* Something happened. :-) Open your web console to see what. The linked question's answers explain why, and what to do instead. In this case, if you just want to change the *first* element with that class, use `document.querySelector(".test2")`. If you want to change them all, use a loop. Happy coding!

Comment: Do like this document.getElementsByClassName('test2')[0].innerHTML = '<div id=test22>Test 2!</div>';
getElementsByClassName returns array so get 0th element